# Why do I keep getting a "warning skipping unreadable file" message with Gnuplot when plotting a .dat file I made using Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gnuplot

Here is the code

```
program plotting
implicit none
real, parameter :: pi = 3.141592
integer, parameter :: n=100
real, dimension(1:n) :: x,y
real :: a=0.0, b= 2*pi
real :: increment
integer:: i

increment = (b-a)/(real(n)-1)

x(1) = 0.0

do i =2 , n
  x(i) = x(i-1) + increment
end do

y = sin(x)


open(unit=25, file='sineplot.dat')
do i=1, n
  write(25, *)  x(i), y(i)      
end do

close (unit=25)

end program
```

But then when I go into GNU plot and type in :
plot 'sineplot.dat' using 1:2

The following message displays:
Warning skipping unreadable file "sineplot.dat"
No data in plot

I've checked the data file and it looks correct, I am thinking that the problem is the terminal type, it is set to the default 'wxt' but I don't know if this is what I should be using for this problem using windows 8.1.

Comment: You are probably only in the wrong directory., so that gnuplot doesn't find the file

Comment: What would be the correct directory? I tried the full path name and it gives me the same result, with both wxt and windows terminals.

Comment: Type `pwd` to see the directory you are in. That must be the one, where the data file is. But using the full path should also work. This is independent of the output terminal. And use `/` as directory separators, also on Windows, to avoid problems with backslashes in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me using gnuplot 5.0 and Windows 7.

You can try the following in a command prompt, but I tried wxt and windows and both work fine for me:

```
gnuplot -p -e "set terminal windows; plot 'sineplot.dat' u 1:2"
```

Could you post your sineplot.dat file?
What separates the columns in your file ( sorry, I don't know fortran). You may have to use `set datafile separator "<sep>"` if your columns are not separated by whitespace.

Comment: That error message doesn't appear if you have a malformed file, only if the file cannot be opened at all (wrong file name, wrong working directory)

Comment: Hmm, I tried that too and I got the following two lines as error message:line 0: warning: Cannot find or open file "swineplot.dat"
line 0: No data in plot

Comment: That's the message you get with version 5.0, earlier versions (tested with 4.6.6) give you the message "warning: Skipping unreadable file ...".

Comment: Yeah, it comes out as just two collumns seperated by whitespace and the version of GNU plot that I have is 4.4 patch level 2.

Also I've tried using the entire path name and that hasn't worked any better.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem. When I typed vi *file name*.dat i noticed that the file does not exits in that folder rather it is *file name*.dat\ which is the that is saved in that particular folder. Just renamed the file and it work.